# Previous Line Indenting on RET

Tags: emacs24.4, terminal-emacs

It seems that whenever I press `RET` on my emacs init.el file comment lines that the previous line just randomly indents ~4 tabs. I only have a simple load path (nothing currently in there really except for load path and load org-mode).

Nothing happens when I press `C-j` in this position, only RET.

I am on Mac OS X 10.10, iTerm 2 using `xterm-256color` but I launch `emacs -nw` with `TERM=xterm-16color` because that is the only way that my colors work correctly.

[image: Before RET]

[image: After RET]

Any ideas of where I should be looking to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it only indent comments or does it affect lisp code as well?  At first guess I'd suspect an open sexp higher up that would indent to there.

Comment: Can you show what Enabled minor modes are active from the output of the command `C-h m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `;;` (or more) instead of `;` and this won't happen.

What you're seeing is (in conjunction with `electric-indent-mode`) expected behaviour, as by convention

> Comments that start with a single semicolon, ‘;’, should all be aligned to the same column on the right of the source code.  Such comments usually explain how the code on that line does its job.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Comment Tips` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The `comment-column` variable determines the level of indentation for this style of comment.